# (1) near null syntax error

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

```
04-24 12:15:21.671: E/AndroidRuntime(26419):java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flocator/com.flocater.Friendfinderactivity}:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error(code 1): , while compiling: select * from null
```

This is the error I am getting every time I am trying to compile..I am a learning android so I don't know much about this...so can anyone help me to fix this issue..
and I am also getting error `Source not found`
so can you help me to sort out with these two problems.

The codes are In `Friendfnderactivity.java`

```
package com.flocater;

import com.flocator.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Friendfinderactivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public static String deviceid = "deviceid";

public static String device_id = "device_id";
public static String user_id = "user_id";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "
            + Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME, null);

    int rows = cursor.getCount();

    if (rows > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        user_id = cursor.getString(0);
        device_id = cursor.getString(3);
    }
    db.close();
    if (device_id.equals(deviceid)) {
        setContentView(R.layout.subscriber);
    } else
        setContentView(R.layout.subscribe);
 }

public void subscribeUser(View v) {
    // get access to views
    EditText editName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editName);
    EditText editPhone = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
    EditText editArea = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editArea);
    EditText editCity = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editCity);

    boolean done = Database.addUser(this, editName.getText().toString(),
            editPhone.getText().toString(), deviceid, editArea.getText()
                    .toString(), editCity.getText().toString());

    if(done) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Subscribed Successfully!",   Toast.Length_Long).show(); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Friendfinderactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Could not subscribe!",                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void addFriends(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddFriends.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void viewFriends(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SeeFriends.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: What is Database here ? Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "
            + Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME, null);

Comment: what is the value of `Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME`?

Comment: *select * from null*, what else could be the value of `Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME` ?

Comment: Database is another java class where its field is described
few code is..
public class Database {
public static String SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME;
 public static String FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME;
}

Comment: `SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME` value is null. Set your table name to this variable. @akashsharma

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear `"select * from null"` That is your SQL query

Here the table name is null.

You just needs to add the table name.
 For example
replace the following line with

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "
            + Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME, null);
```

this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from your_table_name", null);
```

I am just telling the error you modify for your need.